# Is there an organized biblical based reference for pentecostalism?

Tags: biblical-basis, reference-request

So pentecostalism has a lot of its doctrine around personal experience with the Holy Spirit, like speaking in tongues, hearing the Spirit's voice and so on...

I want to find a theological course/book/piece of media that explains those things from the Bible perspective, but I want a very well organized basis, like a theological foundation for it. Because whenever I try looking into it, either the material is very vague about the sources or is very personal-experience relied... Is there any course like that?

Comment: Welcome to the site, karlabos, and for this Q. There are differing views on this. Pentecostals can provide lots of references to show why they believe they are soundly biblical, but others can equally provide lots of references to show where and why they believe Pentecostalism begins to deviate from a biblical basis. To get a well organized, theological basis for your understanding, you would need both sides. Try taking this https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour to see what is looked for with Qs, and how best to scope Qs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resources on Holy Spirit**

Duffield, Guy, Van Cleave, 1983 Foundations of Pentecostal Theology, Los Angeles, Cal.

Gee, Donald, 1980, Concerning Spiritual Gifts, Springfield, Missouri, Gospel Publ.

Hayford, Jack, Baptism of the Holy Spirit, 2004

Iverson, Dick, The Holy Spirit, Portland, Oregon, City Publishing

It is suggested that along with a systematic theological study of the Holy Spirit, that you read a couple history books about the Charismatic manifestations through the centuries. There has been a continual thread of manifestations of spiritual giftings throughout the centuries of the Christian Church's existence. (1 Corinthians 12-14, Noticed that sandwiched between the two chapters on spiritual gifts is "the Love Chapter! Any manifestation must be governed by this Love.)

Keep studying the Bible; it's great for the soul!